# Check whether a node exists when validating config in Symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony, configuration, yaml

I'm trying to validate config in YAML:

```
parameters:
    modules:
        spu-module:
            path:
            requires: ['spw-module']
        spw-module:
            path:
            requires: []
```

with this code:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('modules')
            ->isRequired()
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('requires')
                        ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                    ->end()
                    ->scalarNode('path')->isRequired()->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end();
```

What I'm trying to test is checking whether required module defined in `requires:` exists in current config. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**
I tried to do something like this:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('modules')
            ->isRequired()
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('requires')
                        ->prototype('scalar')
                            ->validate()
                                ->always(function ($v) use ($rootNode) {
                                    if (preg_match('/(spw-)(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)/is', $v)) {
                                        $rootNode
                                            ->children()
                                                ->arrayNode('yui/modules')
                                                    ->children()
                                                        ->arrayNode($v)
                                                            ->isRequired()
                                                            ->cannotBeEmpty()
                                                        ->end()
                                                    ->end()
                                                ->end()
                                            ->end()
                                        ->end();
                                    }
                                })
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                    ->scalarNode('path')->isRequired()->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end();
```

But it doesn't work for me neither.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a Node as Required and the it is not defined in the configs an exception will be thrown.

May you want to define that at least one element is defined in the requires node:

```
->arrayNode('requires')
        ->isRequired()
        ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't solve my problem because I don't know the name of the node. I need to check whether modules defined as required for another module are existing in the config.